# Is Jon Snow the last of his House?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Now we are at the end of *Game of Thrones* and Jon's secret identity is known, by some at least,

> Daenerys is dead and so is Aemon.

Is Jon now the last

> Targaryen

in Westeros or the rest of the world?

Comment: Are you counting illegitimate Targaryen descent? If so, then acknowledged only, or both acknowledged and unacknowledged? Are you counting descent in a female line (where the surname obviously changes)? Or do you just want people whose surname is legally Targaryen?

Comment: Any answer or info as long as it relates to TV show or marked as from the books would be excellent. I'm sure the SE gods will help moderate.

Comment: @MikeScott Targaryean bastards, whether acknowledged or not, are not members of House Targaryen (unless subsequently legitimised) as they cannot use the surname.

Comment: @MikeScott Women of major houses in ASOIAF/GOT do sometimes keep their House names and their husband marries into it.

Comment: My first thought, of course, was "Well, no, there's Arya, and Bran, and..." **Doh!**

Comment: @T.J.Crowder credit really goes to the title edit (think it was the Lethal Carrot).

Comment: @Seamusthedog - Heh, I see what you mean (and [yes, it was](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/revisions/213153/2)).

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Some other candidates, not mentioned in TheLethalCarrot's excellent answer. All these are from the books, which contain vastly more detail than the TV show, and I think the details are sufficiently minor and the books sufficiently old that I won't include spoiler syntax.

**[Tyrion Lannister](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Tyrion_Lannister)**

There are many hints that Tyrion's father is actually Aerys II Targaryen, not Tywin Lannister. Aerys was infatuated with Joanna Lannister, Tyrion's mother, and Tywin sent her back to Casterly Rock to keep her away from Aerys. But she came back to King's Landing for a big tourney the year before Tyrion was born. Tyrion's hair is not Lannister yellow-blond, it's so pale that it's almost white -- or perhaps Targaryen silver. He has one green eye (normal for Lannisters) and one black eye -- or is it dark violet? And Tyrion being a secret Targaryen would fit well with the "Dragon must have three heads" prophecy.

**[House Martell](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Martell)**

Every living Martell (probably; Manfrey is not quite clear) has Targaryen ancestry. An earlier Daenerys Targaryen, a legitimate daughter of Aegon IV "The Unworthy" married Maron Martell and the current Martells are their descendants. In the books, that's Doran, Oberyn, Manfrey, Arianne and Trystane Martell, and the numerous Sand Snakes who are Oberyn's illegitimate offspring.

**[House Plumm](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Plumm)**

Every living member of House Plumm (I'm going to say that clearly includes "Brown Ben" Plumm of the Second Sons, since the dragons like him) also has Targaryen ancestry. Ossifer Plumm married Elaena Targaryen, daughter of Aegon III and sister to Baelor I and Daeron I. Besides Brown Ben, we know of Philip Plumm and his three sons Dennis, Peter and Harwyn.

**[Rennifer Longwaters](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rennifer_Longwaters)**

Only known living member of House Longwaters, descended from the same Elaena Targaryen as House Plumm, but illegitimately.

**[House Blackfyre](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Blackfyre)**

Descended from Daemon Blackfyre, one of the legitimised "Great Bastards" of Aegon IV. The male line is extinct, but it seems likely that there are Blackfyre descendants in the female line in Essos, though we don't know of any.

**[House Baratheon](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Baratheon)**

Stannis Baratheon is still alive (or at least missing and only unreliably reported dead) in the books, and his grandmother was Rhaelle Targaryen who married Ormund Baratheon. That was the basis of Robert's claim to kingship. His daughter Shireen is also alive in the books. (The Baratheons may also have more remote Targaryen ancestry, since it was rumoured that Orys Baratheon was the son of Aerion Targaryen, the Lord of Dragonstone and father of Aegon the Conqueror (and also of Aegon's wives, Visenya and Rhaneys).)

Robert's bastards also have the Baratheon's Targaryen ancestry. Known surviving bastards include Gendry, Edric Storm and Mya Stone.

**Descendants of [Garmund Hightower](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Garmund_Hightower)**

He married Rhaena Targaryen, and they had six daughters. We know nothing about any descendants through those daughters, but there are likely to be some.

**[House Velaryon](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/House_Velaryon)**

House Velaryon intermarried with the Targaryens many times, and Monford and Monterys Velaryon are still alive, as well as Monford's bastard half-brother Aurane Waters.

Comment: If you're going to include people like Stannis who are dead in the show but not (yet) in the books, then you might as well list Daenerys too :-)

Comment: Is it worth mentioning Young Griff/Aegon? Not confirmed, and I imagine that he won't end up being a big deal as he wasn't in the show, but maybe worth flagging.

Comment: @BenGreen Aegon is mentioned in the other answer. I intend this answer to supplement that one, not duplicate it.

Comment: If the Baratheons count, shouldn’t Gendry be included?

Comment: @Jeff Quite right, and I’ll add him.

Answer (score 33):

Of the known family members for House Targaryen we have.

#### Jon Snow (Aegon Targaryen)

He was last seen in Season 8 Episode 6, "The Iron Throne", going north of the Wall to be free and live with the free folk as a free man.

#### Daenerys Targaryen

Died in Season 8 Episode 6, "The Iron Throne", when stabbed by Jon Snow for being ruthless, killing the innocents and not knowing when to stop. Her body was last seen with Drogon flying away from King's Landing who flew east.

#### Viserys Targaryen

Died in Season 1 Episode 6, "A Golden Crown", when Khal Drogo finally gave him his crown... just in molten form and delivered straight to his head.

#### Rhaego

Dany and Drogo's stillborn son shown in Season 1 Episode 10, "Fire and Blood".

#### Maester Aemon

Died in Season 5 Episode 7, "The Gift", in his bed at the Wall.

---

It's worth noting House Baratheon was founded by Orys Baratheon who was said to be the half-brother to Aegon I Targaryen, so we could count Gendry Baratheon as a member of House Targaryen if you wanted to.

> **Robert Baratheon:** House Baratheon was born in the Wars of Conquest, when Aegon the Dragon invaded Westeros. Aegon sent his commander, Orys Baratheon to take Storm's End. Argilac the Arrogant, the last of the Storm Kings, foolishly left the safety of his stronghold, and met the Baratheon warlord in open battle. Argilac was soundly defeated, and Orys took his lands, his holdings and his daughter. Orys was said to be a half-brother to Aegon Targaryen. If this were true a little "blood of the dragon" mingled with that of the stag in those days.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 1 Complete Guide to Westeros, "House Baratheon"</sub>

---

Before the events of the show we also know of those that died during Robert's Rebellion.

- King Aerys II Targaryen
- Queen Rhaella Targaryen
- Rhaegar Targaryen
- Elia Martell (Rhaegar's (ex-)wife)
- Rhaenys Targaryen (Rhaegar's daughter)
- Aegon Targaryen (Rhaegar and Elia's son)
- Lyanna Stark (Rhaegar's second wife)

---

Whilst fAegon (Rhaegar and Elia's son) isn't a thing in the show the Golden Company were still formed from House Blackfyre, a cadet branch of House Targaryen.

> **Jorah Mormont:** The Golden Company began as revenge. On his deathbed, a Targaryen king legitimized all his bastards, either to buy his way into the seven heavens or spite the family left behind. As everyone knew would happen, his Great Bastards weren't satisfied with their father's name and wanted his throne as well, under the banner of the new House Blackfyre.
>
> **Jorah Mormont:** Their trueborn brothers disagreed. When the Blackfyres lost the civil war, they fled to Essos to gather a new army and return for what was theirs. But wars cost money and Aegor Rivers, the leader of the Blackfyre forces who now called himself "Bittersteel", decided he could sell his army's services to other lords while waiting to return to Westeros. The Golden Company was born. For their words they chose "Beneath the gold, the bitter steel" to remind themselves that they weren't just hired killers, but knights of Westeros who would one day retake their home.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 7 Histories & Lore, "The Golden Company"</sub>

However, the Blackfyre line ended when Barristan Selmy killed Maelys on the Stepstones.

> **Varys:** Decades later, Aegon the Unworthy legitimized all of his bastards on his deathbed. Inevitably, the greatest of these – Daemon Blackfyre – declared himself the rightful heir and ignited yet another war for the crown. After much bloodshed, Daemon was killed by an alliance of his half-brothers on the Redgrass Field. All the same, his descendants continued to threaten the Targaryens until half a century later, when Barristan the Bold slew Maelys the Monstrous on the Stepstones, extinguishing Daemon's line.
>
> <sub>*Game of Thrones*, Season 4 Histories & Lore, "The Death of Kings"</sub>

And of course if any did survive to get to Westeros for Cersei they were all pretty much wiped out by Drogon and her forces when Dany attacked King's Landing. There would of course be survivors (unless Grey Worm got to them first) of that battle and still some in Essos (who else would look after the elephants!?) but most are dead.

Comment: It's very unlikely, but some of guys of the golden company might be Targaryen descent. Even the Company has been wiped out, there could be one random survivor somewhere.

Comment: We know the Blackfyres are extinct in the male line. The last one was Maelys the Monstrous, who died at the Battle of the Stepstones. But the female line may survive.

Comment: @MikeScott, but Blackfyres are not the only potential Targaryens male descents, right?

Comment: Wasn't Robert Baratheon's grandmother a Targaryen as well? That way we do not have to go back all the way to the founding of house Baratheon.

Comment: We could also mention that Tyrion was allowed to be close to a dragon, and also that King Aerys used to be very "friendly" with Tyrion's mother Joanna?

Comment: @BebsV That's speculation even in the books where the evidence is stronger, not really worth mentioning in my opinion.

Comment: @Niffler fAegon is the fan name for the character - see [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10640/58193).

Comment: At least the OP had the decency to use the spoilers (`>!`) tag.

Comment: Your quotes say that the line of the leader of the Blackfyres (Daemon Blackfyre) was extinguished (by Barristan the Bold), but it doesn't say anything like that about the rest of the Blackfyres.

Comment: @Lankymart If you’re reading the answer you’ve read the question which states as of the end of the series. I have zero sympathy for you if you continued to read the answer and was then “spoiled”.

Comment: @Lankymart Oh and FWIW I'm the one that added the spoiler markdown to the question and reworded the title so you're welcome :)

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot thanks for the link to the abbreviations, very handy.